# Actionscript 3 - How to keep the value from an event after removing that event

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

I set a value to my xml object (xml = new XML(e.currentTarget.data);) during my event handler function (the function is executed after the event.COMPLETE) and if I trace the object inside my event function handler it shows my xml data.

but if I try to trace it outside the event handler function it doesn't show my xml content. Isn't there a way to get my xml object content value to show in an other function but not in the event handler function?

```
private var xml:XML; 

public function XMLLoader(xmlURL:String) 
{ 
    var xmlURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(xmlURL); 
    var xmlURLLoader:URLLoader  = new URLLoader(xmlURLRequest); 
    xmlURLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlData); 
}

private function xmlData(e:Event):void 
{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlData); 
    xml = new XML(e.currentTarget.data); 
    dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE)); 
    trace(xml); 
} 

public function getXMLData():void 
{ 
     //I've find out that this shows null because this function is faster
     //what do i do? put an event.complete in every following function?
    trace(xml);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: private var xml:XML;

  public function XMLLoader(xmlURL:String) {
   var xmlURLRequest :URLRequest = new URLRequest(xmlURL);
   var xmlURLLoader :URLLoader = new URLLoader(xmlURLRequest);
   
   xmlURLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlData);
  }
  
  private function xmlData(e:Event):void {
   e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlData);
   
   xml = new XML(e.currentTarget.data);
   
   dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
   trace(xml);
  }
  
  public function getXMLData():void {
   trace(xml);
  }

Comment: could you maybe post the code where you instatiate `XMLLoader` and call the `getXMLData()` method?

Comment: public class XMLLoader extends EventDispatcher { 
 private var xml:XML;
 public function XMLLoader(xmlURL:String) {
 var xmlURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(xmlURL);
  var xmlURLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(xmlURLRequest); xmlURLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlData);
  }
  private function xmlData(e:Event):void {
  e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlData);
  xml = new XML(e.currentTarget.data);
  dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
  trace(xml);//this one shows
  }
  public function getXMLData():XML {
   trace(xml); //this one doesn't show
  }
 }

Comment: Could you maybe post the code within your question. That way it's more readable. But what I would like to see is where you call the `getXMLData()` and `new XMLLoader("xmlURL")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//NOTE: USE THIS IF YOU WANT TO ACCESS DIRECTLY TO THE FUNCTIONS OF THIS "CLASS" WITHOUT USING ANY EVENT LISTENER ON THE CLASS CAUSE IT ALREADY HAS ITS EVENT LISTENER ON EACH FUNCTION (THIS CAUSE ONE FUNCTION ONLY getXMLData())

private var xml:XML;

public function XMLLoader(xmlURL:String) 
{

```
     var xmlURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(xmlURL); 
     var xmlURLLoader:URLLoader  = new URLLoader(xmlURLRequest); 
     xmlURLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlData);
```

}

private function xmlData(e:Event):void 
{

```
     e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlData); 
     xml = new XML(e.currentTarget.data); 
     dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE)); 
     trace("1");//this used to come second of getXMLData() but it's solved now
     trace(xml);
```

}

public function getXMLData():void 
{

```
     //This function was coming first so if you don't want to use an event listener outside    
     //this class to wait for event.complete you can use it here to wait for it and access
     //the function directly without being afraid of the object being null:
     addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, go)
     function go(e:Event){
          trace("2"); //now it ONLY comes AFTER the event.complete, no need for external                   listeners over this class. declare the class object and use getXMLData() directly cause it always comes second the event handler xmlData() :)
          trace(xml);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you call `getXMLData()` immediatelly after `XMLLoader()` at that moment `xml` object is still null. Try calling `getXMLData()` **inside** `xmlData()` function and you should see the difference.

Comment: the thing is even after this "xml = new XML(e.currentTarget.data);" in event handler when you want to trace xml outside the event handler the value is not there anymore, at that point it's null, and i'd like for it to be globaly accessable for any function when needed after the event.complete

Comment: In that case it's hard to tell what's the problem. Can you post full code with you calls to `XMLLoader` and `getXMLData`?

Comment: i've already posted what was happening. watch the post bellow. thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling getXMLData() before your URLLoader completes however, in general, the code you are executing is in bad practice.  Actionscript has no blocking whatsoever, so when you instantiate your new URLLoader with your URLRequest, it immediately begins the loading operation.  If your file is cached, for example, your Event.COMPLETE listener may never fire as you are attaching it after you begin your loading operation.

I've attached below the ideal process for creating and loading data:

```
var data:XML;
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoader_completeHandler);
urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("path"));

private function urlLoader_completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    data = new XML(urlLoader.data);
}
```

If you want to apply this to your own XMLLoader class, I've included the "proper" implementation in AS3...however quite verbose.

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;

class XMLLoader extends URLLoader
{
    public function XMLLoader()
    {
        super();
        addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    }

    private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        dispatchEvent(new XMLLoaderEvent(XMLLoaderEvent.COMPLETE, new XML(data)));
    }
}

class XMLLoaderEvent extends Event
{
    public static const COMPLETE:String = "xmlLoaderComplete";

    public var data:XML;

    public function XMLLoaderEvent(type:String, data:XML = null, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false)
    {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);

        this.data = data;
    }

    override public function clone():Event
    {
        return new XMLLoaderEvent(type, data, bubbles, cancelable);
    }
}
```

To use the XMLLoader class:

```
var xmlLoader:XMLLoader = new XMLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(XMLLoaderEvent.COMPLETE, function(event:XMLLoaderEvent):void
{
    trace(event.data);
});

xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("data.xml"));
```

Best of luck!

Comment: I would disagree that this is bad practice.  When you add a responder to a HTTPRequest or RemoteObject, you don't even have access to the token until after you've called send(), and that's what you actually add the responder to.  As long as you don't call any functions in your method body (or dispatch any events that result in a function's being called elswhere), attaching your listener or responder in the next line is perfectly fine. Also note that there's no reason to create a new Event type just to define an Event constant (and URLLoader has all the events it needs).

Comment: @stat this is what i mean; you see you first code, the proper one for opening any xml file? i want the data object to keep the xml content even after the function "urlLoader_completeHandler", so after "data = new XML(urlLoader.data);" it'd be accessible even if a trace data outside the "urlLoader_completeHandler" function, but in case i trace data outside that it says null. isn't there a solution?  so evrytime i need to access data i must go through an event.complete?

Comment: i'll now see the second and third part of the code and i'll tell you something, but the first one sa i said gives the same result as for my code. cheers

Answer (score 0):

change your trace method to indicate if the xml is loaded yet...
you are running into a race condition

```
private var _xmlLoaded:Boolean=false;// add this to see if the xml is loaded
private function xmlData(e:Event):void 
{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlData); 
    xml = new XML(e.currentTarget.data); 
    _xmlLoaded=true;
    dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE)); 
    trace(xml); 
} 
public function getXMLData():void 
{ 
    if (_xmlLoaded)
        trace(xml);
    else
        trace("not yet loaded");
}
```

Comment: i think you're getting what i'm asking, i'll test the code soon and tell you something. cheers